# Unicode characters not rendering properly in HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, unicode, html5-canvas

I am trying to render a unicode treble clef using the HTML5 canvas element. When using the correct character code (specifically 1D120), it renders fine in HTML, but when I try to use it inside of a canvas a weird character appears

The following code is in my javascript file which works its magic on the canvas...

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

context.font = "48px serif";
context.strokeText("\u1D120", 10, 50);
```

```html
<h1>&#x1D120;</h1>

<canvas id="canvas" width="100" height="100">
</canvas>
```

Unfortunately I can't put a picture of the character because my rep is too low as of yet.

Any insight into what might be causing this problem is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: JavaScript gets weird when you're trying to use Unicode characters beyond the range representable with 16 bits.

Comment: Try this: "\uD834\uDD20" (explanation coming)

Comment: For future reference: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d120/index.htm, this sequence is actually in there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JavaScript strings use UTF-16 encoding. Your character requires a two-part escape because it's a <strike>3-byte UTF-8 sequence</strike> codepoint that requires 2 UTF-16 characters.

Stolen from [a blog post by somebody smarter than me](http://www.2ality.com/2013/09/javascript-unicode.html) is this handy function:

```
function toUTF16(codePoint) {
    var TEN_BITS = parseInt('1111111111', 2);
    function u(codeUnit) {
        return '\\u'+codeUnit.toString(16).toUpperCase();
    }

    if (codePoint <= 0xFFFF) {
        return u(codePoint);
    }
    codePoint -= 0x10000;

    // Shift right to get to most significant 10 bits
    var leadSurrogate = 0xD800 + (codePoint >> 10);

    // Mask to get least significant 10 bits
    var tailSurrogate = 0xDC00 + (codePoint & TEN_BITS);

    return u(leadSurrogate) + u(tailSurrogate);
}
```

When you invoke that with your code:

```
var treble = toUTF16(0x1D120);
```

you get back `"\uD834\uDD20"`.

Thanks again to Dr. Axel Rauschmayer for the code above — read the excellent linked blog post for more information.

Comment: Not " because it's a 3-byte UTF-8 sequence", that's actually only a symptom, not the cause.

Comment: @Tomalak yes yes, that's a good point - the problem is that it's out of the range of the code pages directly representable as a single UTF-16 character, but I don't know the terminology for that :)

Comment: Basic multilingual plane. ;) -- And the two UTF-16 characters are called a *surrogate pair*.

Comment: It's actually a UTF-32 representation (leading 0's removed), ie: \u0001d120.

Comment: Just FYI, ES6 allows using `\u{...}`, so `'\u{1D120}'` or `String.fromCodePoint(...codepoints)` (added in ES6 too) will do the same as the given function. And codepoints between `0xD800` and `0xDFFF` are reserved by UTF-16 in Unicode (though ECMAScript 6 doesn't throw any exceptions for that).

Comment: I did need to know if canvas would render this anyways, so +1.

Comment: How would I wrap this function in order to sanitize a string that includes both special unicode characters requiring the two-part escape and regular characters?  Can I pass a regular character through this function? thanks!

Comment: P.S. I did get a "word processor" working, happy to post here if anyone is interested

Comment: @mpsyp yes for "regular" 8- or 16-bit code points this function should just return exactly what you passed it.

Answer (score 8):

Enclose the hex value inside {}, like so:

```
context.strokeText("\u{1D120}", 10, 50);
```