# Javascript Canvas and UNICODE

Tags: javascript, canvas, unicode

I have a Unicode font using `5 digits` for its characters set. Problem is that they don't print in canvases. I want to display character, say, `\u1302b`:

```
ctx.fillText('\u1302b',10,50);
```

displays `a square and a 'b'`.

```
ctx.fillText(String.fromCharCode(parseInt('\u1302b',16)),10,50);
```

has no effect either, nothing displayed.

Are canvases limited to 4 digits UNICODE chars?

Edit: sure, there is a similar question here: [Unicode characters not rendering properly in HTML5 canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29462958/1607043). Apparently, I need to break that 5 digit character code in two 4 digit character codes, using the toUTF16() function provided. OK, but then, how to render them on the canvas? There is no working example given and all I try fails.

Comment: Of course I know I'm not drawing a square, do you read my question? I know perfectly what character it is as well. I have the correct font installed too. But it's now showing correctly in my canvas, and my question is, how to solve that?

Comment: Where am I rude? I repeat: I have the correct font installed, it works fine with my word processor, etc. It's just not working in canvases. None of your jsbin examples works for me. In both cases I see a square. Chrom,e Opera and Firefox.

Comment: I posted an answer, but then deleted it because this question is a duplicate and has already been given a good answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29462958/1607043

Comment: Just read your link. Ok, using toUTF16('\u1302B') returns \uD800\uDC00. Now, how do I render that in my canvas?

Comment: That function takes a integer, not a string (as demoed in the link). Use `toUTF16(0x1302B)`. That gets you: `'\uD80C\uDC2B'`. Then you would use that in the canvas: `ctx.fillText('\uD80C\uDC2B',10,50);`

Comment: DPenner1. In fact, it's working fine in FF, OP and IE but not in Chrome, which I use for my tests. String.fromCodePoint(), which I just found out, is also working very well, but not in Chrome though. I don't get why. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Enclose the hex value inside {}, like so:

```
ctx.fillText('\u{1302b}',10,50);
```