# draw unicode with context.filltext

Tags: canvas, unicode, html5-canvas

```
text = Array(this.battlefield.pointLimit() - this.battlefield.p2.score).join("∞");
context.fillText(text, client.canvas.width / 2, h-5);
```

shows up with 
[image]
How do I draw this symbol with `context.fillText`?

EDIT: I'm trying the function in the comment with

```
text = Array(this.battlefield.pointLimit() - `this.battlefield.p2.score).join(toUTF16(0x221E));`
```

it's printing \u221E

Comment: Check out this [previous SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29462958/unicode-characters-not-rendering-properly-in-html5-canvas) about Unicode on html5 Canvas. If your question ends up being a duplicate of the previous post then you might want to delete this question. :-)

Comment: Thanks didn't find that when I searched (see my post title) I'll try that.

Comment: What exactly do I pass in to that function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
text = Array(this.battlefield.pointLimit() - this.battlefield.p2.score).join("∞");
```

That should be fine.

But: when a browser loads a .js file from a web page, it decodes the bytes of the script to Unicode source code using an encoding which is, by default, the same encoding it is using to decode the bytes of the web page.

It looks like you've saved the .js file in the UTF-8 encoding (which is a good choice in general), resulting in the character U+221E Infinity `∞` being stored as the byte sequence 0xE2, 0x88, 0x9E. But the browser has loaded the file using the Windows code page 1252 encoding, in which that byte sequence decodes to characters `âˆž`.

So you could do one or both of:

1. make sure the HTML page that includes the script is interpreted by the browser as being in UTF-8, for example by adding the `<meta charset="utf-8"/>` tag to the `<head>`.
2. write the script in ASCII-safe form so it works the same across encodings: `.join('\u221E')`.