# Is it possible to use HTML unicodes inside HTML canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to build a two-dimensional chess game and found that there are Unicode for chess pieces built into HTML, is it possible to use those inside a canvas? If so, how?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29462958/unicode-characters-not-rendering-properly-in-html5-canvas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unicode by itself doesn't have anything to do with HTML, though HTML supports [Unicode character escapes](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes).

Regardless, you can just render text in `<canvas>`:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const size = 16;
ctx.font = `${size}px sans-serif`;
ctx.fillText("\u2654", 0, size); // See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_symbols_in_Unicode
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you, I saw another post with the same function but could not solve it, the example helped a lot!